# ActiveMQ Concurrency Issue - Multiple Consumers Consuming the Same Message From Queue

Tags: java, activemq-classic, spring-jms

I'm using Spring JMS and ActiveMQ where I have a client that pushes messages to a Queue and I have multiple consumer threads that are listening and removing messages from the Queue.  Some of the time the **same** messages gets dequeued from the Queue by two consumers.  I don't want this behavior and want to ensure the only one messages is processed by only one consumer thread.  Any ideas on where I've gone wrong?

**Spring 3.2.2 Config:**

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-2.0.xsd">
    <context:annotation-config />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.myapp" />

    <!-- JMS ConnectionFactory config Starts -->
    <bean id="jmsConnectionFactory" class="org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory">
        <property name="brokerURL">
            <value>${brokerURL}</value>
        </property>
        <property name="userName" value="${username}" />
        <property name="password" value="${password}" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="pooledJmsConnectionFactory" class="org.apache.activemq.pool.PooledConnectionFactory"
        init-method="start" destroy-method="stop">
        <property name="connectionFactory" ref="jmsConnectionFactory" />
    </bean>
    <!-- JMS ConnectionFactory config Ends -->

    <!-- JMS Template config Starts -->
    <bean id="myQueue" class="org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQQueue">
        <constructor-arg value="${activemq.consumer.destinationName}" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="myQueueTemplate" class="org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate">
        <property name="connectionFactory" ref="pooledJmsConnectionFactory" />
    </bean>
    <!-- JMS Template config Ends -->

    <!-- JMS Listener config starts -->
    <bean id="simpleMessageConverter"
        class="org.springframework.jms.support.converter.SimpleMessageConverter" />

    <bean id="myContainer" 
        class="org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer">
        <property name="concurrentConsumers" value="${threadcount}" />
        <property name="connectionFactory" ref="pooledJmsConnectionFactory" />
        <property name="destination" ref="myQueue" />
        <property name="messageListener" ref="myListener" />
        <property name="messageSelector" value="JMSType = 'New'" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="myListener"
        class="org.springframework.jms.listener.adapter.MessageListenerAdapter">
        <constructor-arg>
            <bean class="myapp.MessageListener" />
        </constructor-arg>
        <property name="defaultListenerMethod" value="receive" />
        <property name="messageConverter" ref="simpleMessageConverter" />
    </bean>
    <!-- JMS Listener config Ends -->


    <!-- enable the configuration of transactional behavior based on annotations -->
    <bean id="myJMSMessageSender" class="myapp.JMSMessageSender">
        <property name="jmsTemplate" ref="myQueueTemplate" />
        <property name="jmsQueue" ref="myQueue" />
        <property name="messageConverter" ref="simpleMessageConverter" />
    </bean>


    <bean id="myQueueTemplate" class="org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate">
        <property name="connectionFactory" ref="pooledJmsConnectionFactory" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

**ActiveMQ 5.9.1 config:**

```
<broker xmlns="http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core" brokerName="instance8161" dataDirectory="${activemq.data}" persistent="false">

        <destinationPolicy>
            <policyMap>
              <policyEntries>
                <policyEntry topic="&gt;">
                    <!-- The constantPendingMessageLimitStrategy is used to prevent
                         slow topic consumers to block producers and affect other consumers
                         by limiting the number of messages that are retained
                         For more information, see:

                         http://activemq.apache.org/slow-consumer-handling.html

                    -->
                  <pendingMessageLimitStrategy>
                    <constantPendingMessageLimitStrategy limit="1000"/>
                  </pendingMessageLimitStrategy>
                </policyEntry>
              </policyEntries>
            </policyMap>
        </destinationPolicy>

        ... <!-- rest is default ActiveMQ Config -->
</broker>
```

Comment: Are your consumers erroring out prior to ACKing the message that gets delivered twice?  That could certainly explain message redelivery, and if so you'll have to decide whether it's better to get the message more than once (to guarantee you successfully process it once) or to not get it a second time (so you'll never successfully process that message).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most likely, your `myapp.MessageListener` (or one of its dependencies) is not thread-safe and you are seeing cross-talk across the consumer threads.

Best practice is to craft your listener as stateless (no mutated fields in the class). If that's not possible, you need to protect shared variables with locks.

Comment: These suggestions are spot-on for avoiding one of the things that could cause this problem, but thread-safety problems in your message listener aren't the only way to get message redelivery (nor the most likely, in my experience), so I'd be hesitant to state that this is "most likely" the problem.  It's one thing to look at, but don't go down this path to the exclusion of the others.

Comment: I concur; your comments about redelivery are correct, but "Some of the time the same messages gets dequeued from the Queue by two consumers." sounded to me that (s)he was talking about concurrent delivery, not redelivery of a rejected message.

Comment: This definitely could be the way you interpreted it.  If the OP is seeing the right total number of messages processed, but some get processed more than once and some never, then your thread-safety explanation is probably it.  If the OP is seeing more than N attempts to process N messages, then it's probably a redelivery situation (or a situation where messages are getting duplicated somewhere).